# Simplify a equation

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, exponential-sums

I have a problem simplifying the summation here:

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{n}\sum_{y=0}^{x} {n\choose{x}} {x\choose{y}} y!(x-y)!
$$

The last three terms can be simplified to x!, so the current summation becomes:

$$
\sum_{x=0}^{n}\sum_{y=0}^{x} {n\choose{x}} x! = \sum_{x=0}^{n}{n\choose{x}}(x+1)!
$$

Then I get stuck here, it seems it should relate to $e$, please inspire me if any one knows the answer.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001339

Comment: Wolfram alpha found closed form with incomplete gamma function: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+binomial%28n,x%29*factorial%28x%2B1%29+x+from+0+to+n).

Comment: I think that ([tag:sumsets]) is definitely not correct tag for this question; this tag is for question about [sumsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset). And I don't think ([tag:exponential-sums]) fits here either; I guess it is for this kind of exponential sums: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_sum

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica says:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{e n \Gamma (n+2,1)}{n+1}.$$